# How to use active merchant to send money from a Rails app using PayPal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, activemerchant

In my app, every month I have to send money to the people who sell products through my app. I use active merchant to receive money. Can I use it to send money automatically using PayPal? How? If can't, what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at something like Stripe but if you are married to PayPal,
this seems to have a pretty clear explaination: http://dimaspriyanto.com/2010/05/01/simple-paypal-transfer-using-active-merchant/

Comment: Great thanks i'll check it. Is there a way to get the transaction details from it?

Comment: Maybe look into the API a bit more. Specifically: transaction_details(transaction_id) ⇒ Object